# ToDataSourceResult Extension not populating DataSourceResult object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

The extension method that KendoUI adds (ToDataSourceResult), seems to fail on Pages > Page #1. It works fine the first time the page loads, but then when I try to use it with virtual scrolling, to fetch pages, 2,3,4 ... N asynchronously, the method ignores all the data in the IEnumerable object I am trying to transform.

My code is as follows:

I have a MVC controller that fetches data like so:

```
Database database = Database.GenerateDatabase();
ResultSet queryResults = database.GetEvents( 
    FilterHelper.GenerateQueryCriteria((List<IFilterDescriptor>) request.Filters, request.Page, request.PageSize) 
);
```

Database.GetEvents returns an object like so:

```
public class ResultSet {

    public List<ResultSetRow> Set;
    public int PageRowCount;
    public int TotalRecordCount;
}
```

Each ResultSetRow, is an instance of a class that has 1 string, and 2 ints as properties.

At this point, I set a break point and inspect the contents of ResultSet.Set. The database is properly populating the List with as many records as I specified with request.PageSize. I have confirmed that results are being returned for any and all page numbers.

The next stage, everything goes badly:

```
DataSourceResult result = ((IEnumerable<ResultSetRow>) queryResults.Set).ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

I inspect the contents of the DataSourceResult object, and its array property 'Data' is empty.

**Why is my model (ResultSetRow), failing to convert to Kendo's DataSourceResult object?**

Some additional info:

- Aggregates, groups, sorts, and filters are not being used.
- The number of results returned by Database.GetEvents matches the size of the page requested.

Thanks for your help SO community

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main reason for using `ToDataSourceResult()` is that it runs filtering / ordering / grouping / paging on the database server. As such, it works best when given an `IQueryable` that hasn't yet been executed.

It does work on an `IEnumerable`, but then you have to load the entire table into memory, which is not scalable.

Because you only get one page's worth of data, when `ToDataSourceResult` is called, it thinks that is all the data in the database, and so returns an empty list for pages other than the first.

Comment: So then, if I was to ignore the use of DataSourceResult, could I just directly json my List<ResultSetRow> object?

Comment: @JT you could... but Kendo will already generate the correct database query for you, so you'd be reinventing the wheel. And the Kendo version will work when you switch on filtering / ordering / ...

Comment: Ok, based on your feedback I've developed a work around:
int pagenum = request.PageNum;
request.PageNum = 1; DataSourceResult = ...;
request.PageNum = pagenum;

Comment: @Nicolas Unfortunately I can't use an IQueryable interface. Records are fetched from my database using a stored procedure, not using a SQL query.

Comment: @JT Thanks a million! Was having the same issue and I can't use IQueryable either as the data is coming via a REST API. JT's solution worked like a champ!