# at least one object must implement icomparable on datasourceresult

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am debudding the following code and the .ToList() method workds perfectly fine, the exception "At least one object must implement icomparable" is thrown on the last line:

```
var result = response.ToDataSourceResult(request);
```

whats happening here?

```
public DataSourceResult GetProveedores([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))]DataSourceRequest request,string group)
        {
            var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, group);

            var listTmp = new List<Proveedores>();

            List<Proveedores> ListReturn = new List<Proveedores>();

            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in groupPrincipal.Members)
            {
                ListReturn.Add(new Proveedores { nameProveedor = item.SamAccountName, id=count, });

                //ListReturn[count].nameProveedor.CompareTo(item.SamAccountName);
                count++;
            }
            var response = ListReturn.OrderBy(p => p.nameProveedor).OrderBy(s => s.id).ToList();

            var result = response.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: The issue is in `var response = ...`. The error is thrown in the following line because it probably causes the query to enumerate and the type of `nameProveedor` does not implement `IComparable`.

Comment: If `ToDataSourceResult` is the `kendu-UI` [extension method mentioned in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14296025/2592875), then I suspect that your class `Proveedores` needs to implement IComparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the OrderBy parts of this line:

```
ListReturn.OrderBy(p => p.nameProveedor).OrderBy(s => s.id).ToList();
```

If that works in the debugger up to that point, you'll know where to go next.  I suspect that 'nameProveedor' is not a primitive, and therefore LINQ has no way to perform a comparison necessary to make the grid work.